# Telerik Rad Textboxes and javascript issue

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, visual-studio, telerik

I am simply trying to fill a Rad Text box with server data in javascript. The data is placed inside of the textbox but it is not visible until i click on the Rad Textbox.

```
  function pickItem(name, sku, plu, nameBox, sBox, pBox) {

                sBox.value = sku;
                pBox.value = plu;
                nameBox.value = name;
                $find('mdlPopup').hide();
            }
```

I'm sending the parameter in code for the click of a button inside of a Gridview as follows:

```
  button.Attributes.Add("onClick", string.Format("pickItem('{0}',{1},{2},{3},{4},{5});",
                e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Trim(), e.Row.Cells[1].Text.Trim(), e.Row.Cells[2].Text.Trim(), FormViewAccident.FindControl("prodBox").ClientID,
                FormViewAccident.FindControl("SBox").ClientID, FormViewAccident.FindControl("PBox").ClientID));
```

**Again, this works except for the fact that i have to click inside of the textbox. It works perfect if i use a regular asp.net textbox which is inconsistent for this project**

Comment: @Eric, I removed the rad tag as it pertains to `Rapid Application Development` and not the Telerik Rad Tools

Comment: You have XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: Ok. any idea on how i can prevent this?

Comment: To fix the XSS holes, you'll need to escape single quotes, backslashes, and newlines in the strings.  To fix your problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also make sure that nameBox is a reference to the client RadTextBox object, not its DOM element (hint: use the $find method instead of $get).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Telerik's client-side API to change the value.

Change `nameBox.value = name` to `nameBox.set_value(name)`.

For more information, see the [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/input/examples/programming/clientside/apievents/defaultcs.aspx).

Comment: I thought the same exact thing, but i continue to receive this error:
' Object doesn't support this property or method'

Comment: Change it to `set_value`.  The documentation is wrong; you should look at the demo.